# ClassCastException in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a JUnit test case for a method which do not have a business logic except bunch of setters. I am testing it just to get a better code coverage using Cobertura.

I am getting a `ClassCastException` and I am not sure how to resolve this. I know why this occurs but in this particular case I am not sure how I can take care of it in JUnit code.

This is the line which throws exception.
`dto.setValue( ((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID ))[0] );`

MUT

```
 public IClientUserDto mapFieldsToTO( IClientUserDto clientUser, Map<String, Object> httpParams ) {
ESignatureClientDetails details = SecurityUtils.getSecurityObject();

//Map Parameters
List<IClientUserVendorParamDto> params = new ArrayList<IClientUserVendorParamDto>();
IClientUserVendorParamDto dto = new ClientUserVendorParamDto();

dto.setName( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID );
dto.setValue( ((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID ))[0] );
dto.setCreatedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
dto.setLastModifiedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
params.add( dto );

dto = new ClientUserVendorParamDto();   
dto.setName( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_USER_NAME );
dto.setValue( ((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_USER_NAME ))[0] );
dto.setCreatedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
dto.setLastModifiedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
params.add( dto );

dto = new ClientUserVendorParamDto();   
dto.setName( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_PASSWORD );
dto.setValue( ((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_PASSWORD ))[0] );
dto.setCreatedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
dto.setLastModifiedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
params.add( dto );

clientUser.getClientUserVendor().setCreatedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
clientUser.getClientUserVendor().setLastModifiedBy( details.getUserIdentifier() );
clientUser.getClientUserVendor().setClientUserVendorParams( params );
return clientUser;
}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testMapFieldsToTO() throws Exception {
    DocusignVendorDisplay dvd = new DocusignVendorDisplay();
    IClientUserDto iClientUserDto = Mockito.mock(IClientUserDto.class);
    ESignatureClientDetails clientDetails = Mockito.mock(ESignatureClientDetails.class);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.getSecurityObject()).thenReturn(clientDetails);

    Map<String, Object> httpParams = new HashMap<>();
    httpParams.put("AccountId", iClientUserDto);

    iClientUserDto = dvd.mapFieldsToTO(iClientUserDto, httpParams);

}
```

Comment: If you know why the exception occurs, then perhaps you'd spare us the trouble of figuring that out for ourselves?  I mean, puzzles are great and all, but Stack Exchange has a separate site for that.

Comment: I don't understand why developers do not understand the questions. I know the reason behind ClassCast but I am unable to figure out the solution code wise. I've tried this but this throws IndexOutofBounce. Mockito.when(httpParams.get(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(new String[]{});

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that 
 `ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID` is `"AccountId"`,

and you are setting
 `Mockito.mock(IClientUserDto.class);` for `"AccountId"` ,

but getting it as StringArray `((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID ))`.

It is very confusing and difficult for us to understand things because you are not providing us enough informations. For example, we don'd know what dto(`IClientUserVendorParamDto`) is, and `dto.setValue` is suppose to set.
Is it suppose to set IClientUserDto or a String ?

But as for my answer, why don't you try separating this line

`dto.setValue( ((String[])httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID ))[0] );`

like this

```
String[] accountIdArray = httpParams.get( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID ));
String accountId = accountIdArray[0]:
dto.setValue(accountId);
```

and see which line occurs the ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you all for your responses. I had to cast the String into Array of String where I am calling the mocked method.

Corrected Code:

```
@Test
public void testMapFieldsToTO() throws Exception {
    DocusignVendorDisplay dvd = new DocusignVendorDisplay();
    IClientUserDto iClientUserDto = Mockito.mock(IClientUserDto.class);
    ESignatureClientDetails clientDetails = Mockito.mock(ESignatureClientDetails.class);

    String[] accountId = new String[]{"AccountId"};

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.getSecurityObject()).thenReturn(clientDetails);

    Map<String, Object> httpParams = Mockito.mock(Map.class);

    Mockito.when(((String[])httpParams.get(Mockito.any(String.class)))).thenReturn(accountId);

    iClientUserDto = dvd.mapFieldsToTO(iClientUserDto, httpParams);

}
```